# Explanation of CAR, CDR, CADAR, etc

Tags: command, scheme

Can someone please give me a basic explanation of what the variations of `car` and `cdr` do in Scheme?

If I am correct, `car` will return the first item in the list.  `cdr` will return a list excluding the first element.

I'm confused on the other variations of these, more specifically things like `cadar`, `caddr`, `cddr`, etc.

Say I have this as a random example:

```
define X '(a b (c d e))

(car X)
(cdr X)
(cadr X)
(cadar X)
```

`(car X)` would produce *`a`*, `(cdr X)` would produce *`(b (c d e))`*, `cadr` would produce *`b`*.  But I don't know how to infer any other variation of `car`/`cdr` like `cadar`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can infer the meaning of these functions by parsing their name:

between the first letter ('c') and the last ('r'), a 'a' means "the car of" and a 'd' means "the cdr of".

So:

- `cadr` is "the car of the cdr",
- `cddr` is the cdr of the cdr,
- `cadar` is the "car of the cdr of the car" (thus the parameter has to be a list of list),
- etc.

Comment: This really helped!  I never thought about looking in between the c and r, and then looking for either a or d.  This makes the most sense to me at least.

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way is to enter it into a scheme interpreter:

```
(car X)   -> a
(cdr X)   -> (b (c d e))
(cadr X)  -> (car (cdr X))       -> (car '(b (c d e))) -> b
(cadar X) -> (car (cdr (car X))) -> (car (cdr 'a))     -> error
```

When you have more than one `a` or `d`, as you can see from the `cadr` example, you can read it backwards. First take the `cdr` (d) of the argument, then take the `car` (a) from the result, and so on until you get to the first one.